# .concat() method is not working

Tags: javascript

I am running the following `script`

```js
var result = [];
var data1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var data2 = ['d', 'e', 'f'];
for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
  var tepmArray = [];
  var tempArray1 = [];
  tepmArray.push(data1[i]);
  for (var j = 0; j < data2.length; j++) {
    tempArray1 = [];
    tempArray1.push(data2[j]);
    tepmArray.concat(tempArray1);
  }
  result.push(tepmArray);
}
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

It gives following out put

```
[
    [
        "a"
    ],
    [
        "b"
    ],
    [
        "c"
    ]
]
```

I am expect following out put

```
[
    [
        "a", "d", "e", "f"
    ],
    [
        "b", "d", "e", "f"
    ],
    [
        "c", "d", "e", "f"
    ]
]
```

What is wrong with my code.

Comment: Read the documentation of `Array#concat`. Seriously. It's in the first paragraph.

Comment: `.concat()` returns a new array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just map the values of `data1` and concat then the data of `data2` in each iteration for a new array?

```js
var data1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    data2 = ['d', 'e', 'f'],
    result = data1.map(function (a) {
        return [a].concat(data2);
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = [];
var data1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var data2 = ['d', 'e', 'f'];
for(var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
var tepmArray = [];
//var tempArray1 = [];
tepmArray.push(data1[i]);
for (var j = 0; j < data2.length; j++) {
tepmArray.push(data2[j]);
}
result.push(tepmArray);
tepmArray=[];
}
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you should push all the tempArray inside your result array for each loop of your data1 array (so 3 times here) :

```
var result = [];
var data1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var data2 = ['d', 'e', 'f'];
var data1Length = data1.length;

for (var i = 0; i < data1Length; i++) {
    var tempArray = [];
    tempArray.push(data1[i]);
    for(var j = 0; j < data1Length; j++) {
       tempArray.push(data2[j]); 
    }
    result.push(tempArray);
}
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/80zp1hu4/

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = [];
var data1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var data2 = ['d', 'e', 'f'];
for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
    var tepmArray = [];
    var tempArray1 = [];
    tepmArray.push(data1[i]);
    for (var j = 0; j < data2.length; j++) {
        tempArray1.push(data2[j]);
    }
    tepmArray = tepmArray.concat(tempArray1);
    result.push(tepmArray);
}
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');

//You have reinitialized tempArray1 inside inner loop, 
//and concat function returns new array. So you have to reassign it.
```